# Office Store rejects Outlook Module extension Add-in. How to submit only Module extension add-in

Tags: api, outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins, office-store

We have created a outlook Module extension Add-in. it works in outlook 2016 onward as per following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/extension-module-outlook-add-ins . We want to submit this add-in in office store. We have submit it to the office store but store rejects the Add-in on below grounds-

1. The add-in does not appear on Outlook 2013.
2. The add-in does not appear on Outlook 2016 for Mac.
3. The add-in does not appear on Outlook 2016 on Chrome browser.
4. The add-in does not appear on Outlook on Safari browser (Version: 13.1 15609.1.20.111.8)).

Add-in can't be work inside these environment since Module extensions are only supported by Outlook 2016 or later on Windows.

Can somebody help me how i can submit my module add-in which can pass these features?

Comment: outlook Module extension is only supported in Outlook 2016 however, an Outlook add-in must be functional on all of the supported platform's shown when you upload your manifest in Partner Center. There will need to be additional functionality on the other supported platforms to pass certification.

Comment: @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms, In such case how office store will validate our module extension. since our main functionality is module add-in. Can we place a simple page for other plateform? where page can inform user that our module add-in will available in future on this plateform. Either move to Outlook 2016 for windows or we can provide a weblink of the same functionality. please advise. we have totally stuck on it.

Comment: including @office-store

Comment: There would have to be some functionality on the other platforms that would provide value with Outlook, a placeholder or notification that the add-in does not work there would not meet the requirements'.

Comment: @OfficeStoreDeveloperComms we have already a published Add-in in  Store. Can we integrate this module add-in with existing Add-in? How we submit this new module-addin with existing Add-in? What description we need to provide to store to test new integrated Add-in? How the Add-in name will impact existing one? do we have any guideline specific to Module add-in only? Please help me out.